# How do you define the default groups in active directory for new users?

Tags: active-directory

When I create a new user it puts them in domain users.  I have other groups that I wish were there that I have to go back and put them in.  How can I add those to be the default in active directory?

Comment: If this get's migrated to Server Fault, I recommend adding more information about your network/domain, else they might find it too vague

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a template user then copy that user when you create a new person!

Comment: ...and ideally disable the account for the template to prevent anyone accidentally using it.

Comment: yup forgot that little tidbit!

Answer (score 0):

You could use dsadd / dsmod commands to create the account and/or add it to relevant groups, and it's pretty easy to do this in a batch file that you call and provide a user name at the same time. Not a solution to add them by default (tony's answer is correct for that), but maybe better in the long term.

Let's say that today your default is for membership of groups A, B, C.
Next month you change the default to be A, B, C, D, and update your template. But you still have to go and update existing users. The batch scripting method makes it easy to run the same commands against previous accounts too.